# Definition of velocity in the context of affine space

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, vectors, velocity, displacement

In many texts you see the definition of velocity as the time derivative of position. In the context of affine space, position is not a vector quantity. So in the context of affine space, is the correct definition of velocity the time derivative of the displacement instead of the time derivative of the position?

Answer (score 6):

In affine spaces the derivative of a curve $P=P(t)$ is a vector since couples of points uniquely define vectors:
$$P(t + h)-P(t)$$
as a consequence of the affine structure.
As it is a well-defined vector it can be multiplied with a number and the velocity is defined as the limit of the vector valued function
$$\lim_{h\to 0} h^{-1}(P(t + h)-P(t))\:.$$
Evidently, this limit defines a vector as well.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, is $P(t+h)-P(t)$ correctly referred to as a displacement vector or translation vector?